# nginx + php 7 + filter_input + Homestead

Tags: nginx

I need to validate the URL, then the next code is working perfect with php and apache:

```
$url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)
```

Example: Whith this URL: plantilla_mvc.net//////controlador/metodo/////argumentos

it is tranforming to: /controlador/metodo/argumentos (**without //////**)

**BUT with nginx it is not working**.

Then I tryed:

$url = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

But filter_input **DOES NOT work with INPUT_SERVER**

how can I solve this problem??

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a known issue, see https://github.com/xwp/stream/issues/254

> Because of a PHP confirmed bug, filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'anything'
>   ) would return null on some implementations of FCGI/PHP 5.4 ( and
>   probably older versions as well ).
>   https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49184
>
> Use workaround mentioned in
>   https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730094:

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_SERVER, "SERVER_NAME")) {
        $servername = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "SERVER_NAME",
FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
    } else {
        if (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]))
            $servername = filter_var($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"],
FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
        else
            $servername = null;
    }
```